# Tomcat 7 Clustering using IIS webserver

Tags: iis, tomcat, cluster

I successfully configured Apche httpd server for load balancing and clustering od multiple tomcat instances on same machine. Now I need to use IIS web server instead of Apache server. How can I proceed? How will I configure IIS server for tomcat clustering?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with "tomcat clustering", but to have a cluster of IIS servers on one machine you would have to run a few Virtual Machines with the same Windows Server and IIS versions on them.

There are numerous howto's on IIS clustering for [fail-over](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/970759) or [load-balancing](http://www.iis.net/learn/web-hosting/configuring-servers-in-the-windows-web-platform/network-load-balancing). Two installations of the (full blown) IIS server on one OS is not supported. Application pools inside IIS are supposed to provide enough separation (app pools run in their own process). It might be possible to host multiple instances of [iis Express](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line) (not sure, I never tried it), but you will not have any clustering functionality.

What are your requirements? Why do you need IIS? And what kind of clustering do you need? Load balancing or fail-over for 100% uptime while updating?